# jQuery #div scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Look at [this](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_40217/#!/) site.

I want to have the same sliding effect after you click on any menu item. If I click another menu item, the current content shifts out the window and the new content comes from the same side.

I want to know how i can achieve this effect?

Have i made myself clear?

Comment: Can you reword this as it doesnt really make much sense at the moment!

Comment: Also very confused, what do you mean div movement?

Comment: i reword my question.. pls read it again :)

Comment: Are you want to know how to do this effects? Or how to do it all together?

Comment: only the in/out content effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LeGaF/1/

Pure CSS solution (terribly styled, just showing you the idea behind it

Comment: Sadly not with the older versions, but it degrades relatively gracefully (they wont see the transition, but the content will appear and disappear correctly)

Comment: if i can pass this effect to jquery, maybe this works on older versions (IE7, IE8)..because most visitors of the site using IE8..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at jQuery UI ? Checkout those [effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/).

Answer (score 0):

Can't really get what you mean. Do you want to do the exact effect on the site you gave? There are a number of plugins which can do those effects.